# Conditional subtraction Part 2

Tags: r, conditional-statements, multiplication

I have a big data.frame (`TOTAL`) with some values (cols11-16) that I need to subtract a base from which is multiplied by a value depending on two conditions in `TOTAL`.

The data.frame (`TOTAL`) looks a little like this

```
Channel    Hour      Category cols11 cols12 cols13 cols14 cols15 base
TV1        01:00:00  New      2      5      4      5      6      2.4
TV5        23:00:00  Old      1      5      3      9      7      1.8
TV1        02:00:00  New      8      7      9      2      4      5.4
```

There are 4 different channels, and 24 different hours (`00:00:00-23:00:00`)

I have four other vectors with the conditionedvariable that needs to be multiplied on the base depending on the Hour and the Channel, So for each channel I have a vector like this:

```
TV1Slope:
TV1Slope00 TV1Slope01 TV1Slope02.. TV1Slope23
 0.0012      0.0015    0.013       0.0009

TV5Slope:
TV5Slope00 TV5Slope01 TV5Slope02.. TV5Slope23
0.0032      0.0023    0.016       0.002

TOTAL$Uplift0 <- (TOTAL$cols11 - TOTAL$base * conditionedvariable)
TOTAL$Uplift1 <- (TOTAL$cols12 - TOTAL$base * conditionedvariable)
TOTAL$Uplift2 <- (TOTAL$cols13 - TOTAL$base * conditionedvariable)
TOTAL$Uplift3 <- (TOTAL$cols14 - TOTAL$base * conditionedvariable)
TOTAL$Uplift4 <- (TOTAL$cols15 - TOTAL$base * conditionedvariable)
```

How do I make R choose the conditioned variable based on the conditions?

For example:

For `TOTAL$Uplift0` I will get:

```
 cols11 - base * conditionedvariable
```

For the first row where Channel is TV1 and hour is `01:00:00:   2 - 2.4 *0.0015`
For the second row where Channel is TV5 and hour is `23:00:00:  1 - 1.8 *0.002`
For the third row where Channel is TV1 and hour is `02:00:00:   8 - 5.4 *0.013`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We `paste` the 'Channel' and `substring` of 'Hour' column together ('nm1'), concatenate the 'TV1Slope' and 'TV5Slope' vectors ('TV15'), `match` the 'nm1 vector with names of 'TV15' after removing the 'Slope' substring with `sub`, and get the corresponding 'TV15' value.  Subset the columns with names starting with 'cols' using `grep`, do the calculation, and assign it to new columns ('nm2').

```
nm1 <- with(TOTAL, paste0(Channel, substr(Hour, 1,2)))
TV15 <- c(TV1Slope, TV5Slope)
val <- TV15[match(nm1, sub('Slope', '', names(TV15)))]
indx <- grep('^cols', names(TOTAL))
nm2 <- paste0('Uplift',seq_along(indx)-1)
TOTAL[nm2] <- TOTAL[indx]-(TOTAL$base*val)
TOTAL
#  Channel     Hour Category cols11 cols12 cols13 cols14 cols15 base   Uplift0
#1     TV1 01:00:00      New      2      5      4      5      6  2.4 1.9946026
#2     TV5 23:00:00      Old      1      5      3      9      7  1.8 0.9823184
#3     TV1 02:00:00      New      8      7      9      2      4  5.4 7.9619720
#   Uplift1  Uplift2  Uplift3  Uplift4
#1 4.994603 3.994603 4.994603 5.994603
#2 4.982318 2.982318 8.982318 6.982318
#3 6.961972 8.961972 1.961972 3.961972
```

NOTE: Created reproducible 'TV1Slope' and 'TV5Slope' examples

#### data

```
TOTAL <- structure(list(Channel = c("TV1", "TV5", "TV1"), Hour = c("01:00:00", 
"23:00:00", "02:00:00"), Category = c("New", "Old", "New"), cols11 = c(2L, 
1L, 8L), cols12 = c(5L, 5L, 7L), cols13 = c(4L, 3L, 9L), cols14 = c(5L, 
9L, 2L), cols15 = c(6L, 7L, 4L), base = c(2.4, 1.8, 5.4)), .Names = c("Channel", 
"Hour", "Category", "cols11", "cols12", "cols13", "cols14", "cols15", 
"base"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

set.seed(24)
TV1Slope <- setNames(runif(24)/100, sprintf('TV1Slope%02d', 0:23))
set.seed(29)
TV5Slope <- setNames(runif(24)/100, sprintf('TV5Slope%02d', 0:23))
```